# YouTube API Data Foreach Loop (Retrieve First Video ID)

Tags: php, json

I've been using YouTube API to list the Title and Video ID and other details. I'm able to list them in foreach loop. e.g all the Titles and Video IDs. But, when i'm trying to get the first title only (from JSON response) it outputs nothing.

I've used [0] but it doesn't work at all.

```
$file1 = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$id&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
$file1 = json_decode($file1, true);
foreach($file1['items'] as $items1){
$first_id = $items1[0]['id'];
$first_title =  $items1[0]['snippet']['title'];
$all_id .= $items1['id'];
$all_title .= $items1['snippet']['title'];
}
```

Here's the JSON File:
pastebin.com/d7UynbdG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only first video item you don't need `foreach`. You can just get first element of array.
For example:

```php
$first_id = $file1['items'][0]['id'];
$first_title = $file1['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
// foreach loop....
```

But if you want to split first item and rest, just use `array_shift` for items:

```php
$restItems = $file1['items'];
$firstItem = array_shift($restItems);
```